# Error 400 when making POST request to Spotify API with Axios on Express.js

Tags: node.js, express, axios

I'm trying to retrieve an access token from the Spotify API when making a post request with axios on an Express back end server. So far I have been unsuccessful. I'm getting the following error:

data:
      { error: 'unsupported_grant_type',
        error_description:
         'grant_type must be client_credentials, authorization_code or refresh_token' } } }

I've already tried to change 'data' property for 'grant_type' to 'params' but it's still not working. Any advice would help.

```
const express = require('express');
const axios = require('axios');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
dotenv.config();
const app = express();
const port = 3000;

const client_id = process.env.CLIENT_ID;
const client_secret = process.env.CLIENT_SECRET;

app.get('/spotify-authorization', (req, res) => {
  axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: 'https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token',
    data: {
      grant_type: 'client_credentials'
    },
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      Authorization:
        'Basic ' +
        Buffer.from(client_id + ':' + client_secret).toString('base64')
    }
  })
    .then(response => {
      console.log(response.data);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
    });

  res.send('successful response received!');
});

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Express app listening on port ${port}!`));
```

I want to be able to retrieve the access token in the response from the Spotify API. Please help!

Comment: I did already try that with both 'param' and 'params' but received the same error unfortunately.

Comment: From docs: `grant_type Required. As defined in the OAuth 2.0 specification, this field must contain the value "authorization_code".` Change `grant_type: 'client_credentials'` to `grant_type: "authorization_code"`

Comment: The grant_type needs to be 'client_credentials' as per the Client Credentials flow on the Spotify API docs.

Comment: this link or different? https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization-guide/

Comment: Yes that's the link. I'm looking at the Client Credentials Flow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From `axios` docs : `By default, axios serializes JavaScript objects to JSON. To send data in the application/x-www-form-urlencoded format instead, you can use one of the following options.`

For Nodejs you can use the [`querystring`](https://nodejs.org/api/querystring.html) module as follows:

```
var querystring = require('querystring');
axios.post('http://something.com/', querystring.stringify({ foo: 'bar' }));
```

So, in your case you could try `data: querystring.stringify({ grant_type: 'client_credentials' })`

Comment: I tried that but I'm now getting a 400 error with the following message:

  data:
      { error: 'invalid_client', error_description: 'Invalid client' } } }

Comment: sounds like authentication issue, Could you try hitting with `Postman` and check if the response code is 401 or 403 (use node to convert to base64 or you can do it online)

Comment: So I tried with Postman and I got a successful response (200). I then copied Postman's own version of the base64 encoded authorisation header into the post request in my express.js file and it worked. So this lead me to believe there was something wrong with environment variables. Turns out I was storing the .env file in the directory above my server file which was preventing it from loading those same variables. As soon as I moved them into the same directory the request worked. Thanks for your help much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I can't leave a comment due to low reputation, but 1556089774's answer should be the accepted answer. I've spent over 4 hours researching as to why it wasn't working since Spotify's iOS sdk points to https://glitch.com/~spotify-token-swap as an example which does NOT WORK. Adding the stringify to the data part of the request makes it work:

```
data: querystring.stringify ({
  grant_type: "authorization_code",
  redirect_uri: SPOTIFY_CLIENT_CALLBACK_URL,
  code: authorization_code
})
```