# Invoking Spotify API from lambda function

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, api, aws-lambda, spotify

I need to get data from Spotify API then send the response to the front-end. To avoid CORS issue and to hide key and secret from Spotify, I would like to use Lambda to make the API call then send back the response. To be more precise about my application:

```
1. FrontEnd > API Gateway
2. API Gateway > Lambda
3. Lambda > Spotify API (request their API to get token)
4. Spotify API > Lambda (token in the response)
5. Lambda > API Gateway
6. API Gateway > FrontEnd
```

Spotify endpoint is:

```
https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token?grant_type=client_credentials
```

Header is:

```
Content-Type: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
Authorization: 'Basic XXX'
```

So far I was able to do this using a Lambda function:

```
const https = require('https');
exports.handler = async (event, context) => {

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const options = {
          hostname: 'accounts.spotify.com',
          path: '/api/token?grant_type=client_credentials',
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'Authorization': 'Basic XXX'
          }
        }

        const req = https.request(options, (res) => {
          res.on('data', function (chunk) {
            console.log('BODY: ' + chunk);
          });
          resolve('Success');
        });

        req.on('error', (e) => {
          reject(e.message);
        });

        // send the request
        req.write('');
        req.end();
    });
};
```

But I can't get the response from the API:

```
{
    "access_token": "YYY",
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "expires_in": 3600,
    "scope": ""
}
```

And I don't know how to send the data back to the front-end. Do you have any guidance to achieve what I'm looking for?

Edit: I also tried using axios as suggested:

```
const axios = require("axios");

module.exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    const headers = {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'Authorization': 'Basic XXX'
          }
    axios.post('https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token?grant_type=client_credentials', {}, {
      headers: headers
    })
    .then(function(response) {
        console.log(response)
        callback(null, response);
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
       console.error("Error: " + err);
       callback(err);
    });
};
```

But got the following error:

```
Response:
{
  "errorType": "Error",
  "errorMessage": "Request failed with status code 400",
  "trace": [
    "Error: Request failed with status code 400",
    "    at createError (/var/task/node_modules/axios/lib/core/createError.js:16:15)",
    "    at settle (/var/task/node_modules/axios/lib/core/settle.js:17:12)",
    "    at IncomingMessage.handleStreamEnd (/var/task/node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js:237:11)",
    "    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:215:7)",
    "    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1183:12)",
    "    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21)"
  ]
}
```

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your question but what do you mean by "sending something from lambda to front end" ?

Comment: The response is not complete until `res.on('end')` happens. You should probably also consider using Axios or similar rather than the native `https` package because it will make life simpler and better.

Comment: @AshishModi I've updated my question to be a bit more precise. Spotify API send me a token inside the response. I want to get the token and send it to my front-end (I'm using API gateway between my front-end and lambda)

Comment: @jarmod Thanks for your reply, I will try using Axios in AWS Lambda if it will make my life easier :)

Comment: Be aware that you will have to package Axios with your uploaded Lambda function (or use a pre-created Lambda Layer with Axios installed). Minor headache if you are currently just uploading code or using the built-in Lambda function editor.

Comment: @jarmod i was able to get my token using res.on('end') but didn't really know what to do with the response. So I tried to use Axios as you suggested but get an error (I've updated my question).

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55460718/error-400-when-making-post-request-to-spotify-api-with-axios-on-express-js

Comment: @jarmod Following your link, and your help, the solution I posted below works for me. In order to help other people - myself included - don't hesitate if you find any improvement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @jarmod and @Ashish Modi, the solution below is working for me:

```
const axios = require("axios");
const querystring = require('querystring');

module.exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    const headers = {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'Authorization': 'Basic XXX'
          }
    axios.post('https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token?grant_type=client_credentials', querystring.stringify({}), {
      headers: headers
    })
    .then(function(response) {
        const res = {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: (response.data.access_token)
    };
        callback(null, res);
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
       console.error("Error: " + err);
       callback(err);
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
const https = require('https');
function hitApi() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const options = {
      hostname: 'accounts.spotify.com',
      path: '/api/token?grant_type=client_credentials',
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Authorization': 'Basic XXX'
      }
    }
    https.request(options, (res) => {
      res.setEncoding("utf8");
      let body = "";
      res.on('data', function (chunk) {
        body += chunk;
      });
      res.on("error", err => {
        reject(err);
      });

      res.on('end', function () {
        resolve(body);
      });
    });
  });
}

exports.handler = async (event, context) => {

  const result = await hitApi();
  return result;

};
```

hope this helps

Comment: Thanks @Ashish Modi but when using your code I've got :
Response:
{
  "errorMessage": "2019-12-12T14:40:11.706Z 3b17c168-034b-43b0-97f1-de5f0bf387f9 Task timed out after 3.00 seconds"
}

Comment: You should simply `return hitApi();` rather than await the result and then return the result.

Comment: That is lambda timeout - 3 seconds. You should change it as per your requirement. Looks you need more as yiur operation is not getting completed